# Sequence of coprime integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am working on this problem:

> Let $f(x)=x^2-2x+2$. Define a sequence
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> a_0&=3\\
> a_1&=f(a_0)=5\\
> a_2&=f(a_1)=17\\
> &\vdots\\
> a_n&=f(a_{n-1}).
> \end{align*}
> $$
> Prove that, for all $n$, if $p$ is a prime dividing $a_n$, then $p$ does not divide any $a_m$, where $m>n$.

**What I've done so far**: I know that if $x$ and $y$ are integers then $x-y$ divides $f(x)-f(y)$, since $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. Therefore, if $p$ divides both $a_n$ and $a_m$, then $p$ divides $a_m-a_n$, so $p$ divides $f(a_m)-f(a_n)=a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}$, and so on. However, I am stuck trying to reach a contradiction. Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $p$ divides $a_n$, then

$$ a_{n+1} = f(a_n) = a_n^2 - 2a_n + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod p $$

What happens next?

Comment: Is this a know function? like a consequence of some theorem?

Comment: Well, the only theorem I see here, is that $f(x) \equiv f(y) \pmod m$ whenever $x \equiv y \pmod m$, for any polynomial $f$ (which is an easy consequence of the fact that $x-y \mid f(x)-f(y)$).

Comment: Yeah, I mean some characterization of such function

Comment: Well, we only use that $f$ is a polynomial and $f(0)=f(f(0))$, so all such functions will work.